# Is it possible to calculate joint PDF in this case?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(x_1, \ldots, x_k, \ldots, x_K)$ be a set of $K$ positive and continuous i.i.d. random variables with known distribution.

We have a function with a single parameter $\lambda_n$ that maps the $K$-dimensional set $(x_1, \ldots, x_k, \ldots, x_K)$ to a single real positive number $y$, that is, $y \triangleq f(\lambda_n; \ x_1, \ldots, x_k, \ldots, x_K)$. The distribution of $y$ as a function of the distribution of $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^K$ is also known.

Now we create a set of random variables $y_n$ by changing the parameter $\lambda_n$, for the same set of input variables $(x_1, \ldots, x_k, \ldots, x_K)$. That is:

$y_1 = f(\lambda_1; \ x_1, \ldots, x_k, \ldots, x_K)$

$y_2 = f(\lambda_2; \ x_1, \ldots, x_k, \ldots, x_K)$

and so on up to

$y_N = f(\lambda_N; \ x_1, \ldots, x_k, \ldots, x_K)$

So now we have a set of $N$ random variables $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^N$ which are not independent since of all them have been generated from the same set $(x_1, \ldots, x_k, \ldots, x_K)$.

Is it possible to calculate the joint distribution of the variables $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^N$ with the information given above?

For information, the function $f$ is defined as:

$f(\lambda_n; \ x_1, \ldots, x_k, \ldots, x_K) = - \lambda_n \ln \left( \frac{1}{K} \sum_{k=1}^K e^{-\frac{x_k}{\lambda_n}} \right)$

Comment: What is the connection to [distribution-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distribution-theory)?

Comment: Sorry, it's now fixed